# ESC Closes Both Fullscreen Windows On Firefox 79.0

Tags: windows-10, firefox, fullscreen

I have 2 monitors. When I have a fullscreen stream on both of them, I'll usually default to using Esc to exit the fullscreen I'm watching (and which technically is the window in focus) but this results in both of them exiting fullscreen mode. Is there a way to change this behavior on FF version 79.0?